# Need to reconnect power supply to boot windows 8.1/10

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios, power-supply

**Please let me know if it is offtopic here. I am facing some hardware problem may be that's why I am posting it here**

I have a desktop pc with dual boot(ubuntu14.04 and windows 10).

1. Motherboard: intel dh61ww classic
2. RAM: 6GB
3. HARD DRIVE: seagate 320GB
4. Processor: Dual Core.

Problem is, If i restart the pc i can not boot into windows10 (but boot into ubuntu is working fine). I have to disconnect power supply and reconnect it to boot into windows. And one more thing each time i boot into windows 10 the network adapter is missing and I have to fix it via troubleshooting and restart my pc to get into internet.

I have searched a lot but couldn't find any solution. If you please help me i will be grateful to you.

Thank you.

N:B: if you need more info just ask in comment. I will provide them.

Comment: What's actually happening if you try to boot into Windows?

Comment: @Seth 

Step 1. When I try to boot into windows I stuck at windows logo. 
Step 2. Then if I disconnect and reconnect my power supply unit I can boot into windows.
Step3. after I successfully boot into windows my network adapter is gone. I have to manually troubleshoot it and then I am at step 1 again. After step 1 for 2nd time windows works fine.

Comment: @InsomniacSabbir Have you tried some of the simple diagnostics? Boot into Safe Mode or run CHKDSK. Also, did this start after you made any changes to your computer? If so, that would help narrow down where to look. And since it looks like it's trouble with Windows, you might as well backup your license, files, make a system image and do a fresh install. Since you'll lose nothing but a few hours of time, the fresh install won't hurt.

Comment: What happens if you shut down your computer by running the command `shutdown /s` then start it back up without dis/reconnecting the power supply?